# Reproject SRID using DotSpatial

Tags: c#, gis, dotspatial, srid

I'm nota GIS guy so I need some help.  I need to reproject from one SRID to another.  I'm trying to take global lat/longs (4326), reproject them to a local SRID (2336).  This is basically the line of code I'm using.  I keep getting back NaN.  I've tried reversing the lat/long.  Should I be using a different Z value?  What am I doing wrong?

```
DotSpatial.Projections.Reproject.ReprojectPoints(
new[] { -81.25784159999999, 29.4660863 },
new[] { 0d },
ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326), ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(2336),
0,
1);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So I learned it needs to be long, then lat - but I'm still getting NaN as a result.

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out to me, I mistyped the SRID in the "projected to".  Should be 2236, not 2336.  That did the trick.